# Moments How to get the difference between hours

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm trying to create a reminder for hours I'm using momentsJs, `var subtract = moment.duration (b - l) .hours ();` Then at the time of the conversion I get the difference between the current and fixed time, now the problem I have is when the clock goes to the next day the conversion does not take into account that it comes from 22:00 to 02:00 am the other day. Think of replaying 24 hours but some will not get the right difference is there any more effective way to perform the calculation?

**My solution was to implement the twix library which gives me a difference in hours with the following line of code**

`var subtraction = moment(b).twix(l).length("hours");`

I leave my code.

```
        timer4: function(timer){
           var t =  Meteor.users.find({ id: this.userId}).fetch();
            for (var k = 0; k < t.length; k++) {
                var tzone = t[k].profile.timezone;
                var data = AddMed.find({ userId: t[k]._id}).fetch();
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var TimerD = momentT.tz(timer,tzone).format('HH:mm');
                  var h = data[i].time;
                  var resultado = data[i].createdAt       
                   var b = moment(TimerD,'HH:mm');
       var asd = momentT.tz(data[i].createdAt,tzone).format('HH:mm');
                   var l = moment(asd,'HH:mm');
                   console.log('creadoConvertido:', l)
                   console.log('timerServerConvertido:', b)
                   var resta =  moment.duration(b - l).hours();
                   resta = Math.abs(resta);
            var hSystem = momentT.tz(timer, tzone).format('HH:mm');
                   var fecha = moment(new Date).format('YYYY-MM-DD');      
              if ( fecha == data[i].date && data[i].time == hSystem) { 
 Meteor.call('AddCheckInit', data[i]._id,t[k]._id,k, function(error) { 
                 if (error) { 
                    console.log('error', error); 
                     } 
                  });
               }  
  if (resta == data[i].recordatorio && data[i].check == 'true'){
                 console.log('entre remminder')
                    var SendP = {
                        name: data[i].NameMed,
                        detalles: data[i].detalles,
                        date: data[i].date,
                        time: data[i].time,
                        recordatorio: data[i].recordatorio,
                        idioma: t[k].profile.idioma,
                        userid: t[k]._id,
                        id: data[i]._id,
                        type: 'medicinas',
                        createdAt: data[i].createdAt,
                        k:i,
                        resta: resta
                      }
/// send push notifications
      Meteor.call("serverNotification",SendP);
      Meteor.call('updateCreated', SendP,k, function(error, success) { 
                        if (error) { 
                          console.log('error', error); 

                        } 
                        if (success) { 
                           console.log("Cambios Realizandos Existosamente")
                           console.log('succes',success.createdAt)
                        } 
                      });
                     } 
                     else {
                       console.log('contando. medicinas');
                     }
                       console.log('/****end logs*****/');
                    }

                 /*****************end************************/
                }

            }

   //**** My meteor Methodos ***********/
     updateCreated: function(SendP,k){
      var t =  Meteor.users.find({ id: this.userId}).fetch();
      var tzone = t[k].profile.timezone;
       console.log('mi zona', tzone)
       var createdAt = momentT.tz(new Date(), tzone).format();
                  console.log('creado el',createdAt);
                  AddMed.update({
                      '_id': SendP.id
                  }, {
                      '$set': {
                         'createdAt': createdAt,
                      }
                  });
                  return createdAt;
              },
     AddCheckInit: function(id,userId,k){
      console.log('AddCheckInit',id,'USER',userId);
       var t =  Meteor.users.find({ id: this.userId}).fetch();
       var tzone = t[k].profile.timezone;
       console.log('mi zona', tzone)
      var createdAt = momentT.tz(new Date(), tzone).format();
      console.log('creado el',createdAt);
      AddMed.update({
                '_id': id
              }, {
            '$set': {
          'check': 'true',
         'createdAt': createdAt,
          }
          });
          } ,
```

Comment: Please read about using a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was based on the following

```
  timer4: function(timer) {
    var checkSendP = false;
    var t = Meteor.users.find({
      id: this.userId
    }).fetch();
    for (var k = 0; k < t.length; k++) {
      var tzone = t[k].profile.timezone;
      var data = AddMed.find({
        userId: t[k]._id
      }).fetch();
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        /*----------------------GLOBAL-------------------------*/
       var TimerD = momentT.tz(timer, tzone).format('HH:mm');
       var fecha1 = momentT.tz(timer, tzone).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
       var fecha2 = moment(data[i].createdAt, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
       var resta = Math.abs(fecha2.diff(fecha1, 'H'));
       var hSystem = momentT.tz(timer, tzone).format('HH:mm');
       var fecha = moment(new Date).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
       /*-----------------------------------*/
        console.log('/*Server logs CronJobs*/');
        console.log('profileName:', t[k].profile.name);
        console.log(`medicina ${data[i].NameMed}`);
        console.log('tzone:', tzone);
        console.log('DateSistema:', new Date())
        console.log('UTC:', momentT.tz.guess());
        console.log("fecha1", fecha1);
        console.log("fecha2", fecha2);
        console.log('cTimer:', TimerD);
        console.log('created el:', data[i].createdAt)
        console.log('timerCronJobs:', timer);
        console.log('resta Abs:', resta, 'Horas');
        console.log('recordatorio', data[i].reminder);
        console.log('resta', resta);
        console.log('date', data[i].date);
        console.log('fecha', fecha);
        console.log('hSystem', hSystem);
        console.log('hora', data[i].time);
        /*-----------------------------------*/
        /*-------------------GLOBAL-----------------------*/
        var SendP = {
          name: data[i].NameMed,
          detalles: data[i].detalles,
          date: data[i].date,
          time: data[i].time,
          recordatorio: data[i].recordatorio,
          idioma: t[k].profile.idioma,
          userid: t[k]._id,
          id: data[i]._id,
          type: 'medicinas',
          createdAt: data[i].createdAt,
          k: i,
          resta: resta
        }
        if (fecha == data[i].date && data[i].time == hSystem) {
          console.log('entre');
          Meteor.call('AddCheckInit', data[i]._id, t[k]._id, k, function(error) {
            if (error) {
              console.log('error', error);
            }
          });
        }
          console.log('check',data[i].check);
          console.log(resta == data[i].reminder && data[i].check == 'true');
        if (resta == data[i].reminder && data[i].check == 'true') {
          console.log('entre remminder');
          data[i].checkSendP = 'true';
        }
        console.log(data[i].checkSendP)
        if (data[i].checkSendP == 'true') {
            data[i].checkSendP = 'false'
           Meteor.call("serverNotification", SendP);
           Meteor.call('updateCreated', SendP, k, data[i].checkSendP, new Date(), function(error, success) {
             if (error) {
               console.log('error', error);
             }
             if (success) {
               console.log("Cambios Realizandos Existosamente")
               console.log('succes', success.createdAt)
             }
           });
        }
        console.log('/****end logs*****/');
      }

      /*****************end************************/
    }
```